# Blank link losing parameters in IE on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have an application to which I have just added a banner cookie for browsers to acknowledge acceptance of cookies.

I have borrowed quite a bit of the jquery code form a different site in our organisation.  There are o problems on this site but it is a static site whereas my app is a REST app.

Essentially the banner has text and links on it and a 'button' (link) to accept and remove the banner.

This is like this

```
<a href="" class="tick" id="impliedok">I understand<a>
```

In chrome this works fine everywhere.  On the static site this works fine and on some pages in my application this works okay.  Presumably there is something under the browser hood which makes a blank link point to the current page as if I hovver over the link I get a short cut.  In chrome it is the correct shortcut but in IE the link is to the shortcut with no parameters, so for example

```
http://localhost:8080/search/account?term=*
```

seems to link to

```
http://localhost:8080/search/
```

in IE (8 and 11).  But links to the full URL in Chrome.

Is there a simple fix for this ?

Apologies I have not done too much investigation on this yet as it is meant to go live this evening.  I just wondered if it was an obvious gotcha someone could point out to me before I postpone go-live and rip it all apart!?

Comment: Try using `href="#"`

Comment: Thanks this works without a hitch but does leave an untidy # at the end of the url displayed.  I would have accepted this (although whether the business would is more relevant I guess...) but I have opted for $(location).attr("href").  Many thanks though.

Comment: Not sure why you would have a link without an href in the first place...

Comment: To be honest I borrowed the (quite sophisticated) script from someone else.  I think it is just used as a simple way to provide a close button in the format required (there is an associated function added later to close the banner).  I guess it is not the only way but it didn't cause the original author any issues (and got missed all the way through testing!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I deserve the downvote on the basis that I could have put this answer in very easily and either not asked the question or asked if there is a more elegant solution.

I have opted for explicitly using

```
$(location).attr("href")
```

which I was trying to avoid simply because I assumed I'd missed somethign very obvious.

Please let me know if I have made a big mistake.  If you think this is really too simple to be useful as a question add some downvotes and I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo,

```
<a href="" class="tick" id="impliedok">I understand<a>
```

should be

```
<a href="" class="tick" id="impliedok">I understand</a>
```

if that doesn't fix it you can try to add onclick event to the link

```
<a href="" class="tick" id="impliedok" onclick="location.href='pageurl.html';">I understand</a>
```

Comment: Apologies the typo was mine in the question only and not in the code.  onclick="location.href='pageurl.html';" doesn't seem to make any difference but I'll investigate it a bit more to see if I'm missing the point...